# change font size of template zebra printer

Tags: c#, printing, fonts, zebra-printers

We are printing labels to printer directly. The printer is Zebra.
We are using templates to define fields. Here is line which i want to change font size a bit more bigger

```
^FT465,819^A0N,56,55^FH\^FD<Address>^FS
```

You can see that its Address field. I want to change font to be bit bigger but i have no clue what this code. I read a bit and its ZPL code but dont know how i change font size for that field. Has anyone experience with zebra printing. I am printing programatically through c#

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
^XA
^FO485,945^CF0,60^FD<Address>^FS
^FO485,900^CF0,40^FD<Address>^FS
^XZ
```

You can see I change font size from 60 pixels to 40 pixels.